# What kind of non-lethal attacks can a robot use against humans?

Tags: android

I have an android, U-1 who is linked to other androids of the same series for information. The android has muay thai fighting capabilities, but no other special non-lethal weapons. I am especially interested in ranged attacks.

The android's housing is a light metal alloy that can stop most bullets, but not all. Lucid androids, like most in my universe are powered by (PAM) pneumatic air muscles.
The situation I have in mind is that the android has taken over a highly sensitive communication hub area that the government does not want damaged. So the android has taken the area hostage.

The humans have an array of very lethal weapons, but they don't want to destroy the equipment in the room. They also know that the android has a plasfusion rifle, which is deadly and highly destructive, but don't know that the android does not want to use it on them. I thought about turning down the power on the Plasfusion rifles, but I want them to remain highly unpredictable. They can explode if overheated.

An idea that occurred to me after I submitted this question is to have U-1 use the communications equipment to send microwaves throughout the building, which according to the US army would send them to the ground in pain, but do no permanent damage.

I would like to have a series of scenes where U-1 is attacked in different ways but each time the attack is stopped. For instance, the police will send in officers with heavy 6-gage shotguns with "robot slugs" in place of shotgun shells. They will follow some small tracked recon bots.

So the key question I am asking is; what kind of attacks/counterattacks can U-1 use when without conventional weaponry?

Any fighting between an android and a human could easily turn lethal, and that is okay. U-1 will pull punches, but not avoid fighting altogether.

Comment: What does your android look like? What materials is it made of. What type of actuation does it use? What weapons do humans have access to?

Comment: You may want to tell us why the options for a human are out of the scope of this question. Otherwise the answer would be: the same you can see for example with riot police.

Comment: You need to actually state the question within the body of the question or things get more than a little vague, I can't tell what information you're really looking for here.

Comment: 5th degree black belt talking - Martial arts capabilities are primarily overall athleticism, with one rank of dan (Black belt) corresponding to 10 lbs of weight advantage up to 4th dan. The focus of traditional martial arts (as opposed to sport martial arts) is to preserve one's life, so any real combat (as opposed to friendly sparring) is likely to result in death or disability.

Comment: How about a net launcher? Or a chloroform-smoke grenade?

Comment: Hey Den, welcome to worldbuilding! I noticed you say the android has no other non-lethal weapons other than martial arts, yet you are interested in ranged attacks. Can you clarify what you are looking for? Do you want martial arts take-down and submission techniques, or suggestions for a ranged nonlethal weapon?

Comment: Maybe trying to hack into the android communicating system and insert a computer virus is the best non-lethal weapon, and will not damage the combat area by any means.

Comment: Do what Arnold did in *Terminator 2* when Edward Furlong told him not to kill people: shoot them in the knees.

Answer (score 9):

A very special form of sonic attack called verbal abuse.

You android is very tenacious and people don't want to start a fight near sensitive equipment. This reminds me a lot of GLaDOS. Anyway, if the bot is linked to others, and they have access to social media, it can break the morale of any human team.

Imagine the following dialogue:

- Open up HAL, we don't want to extrude you by force.
- Oh hi Mark. Did you know your wife is cheating on you? She is doing it right now. I can see through the webcam of her laptop. She's saying she is going to fill in a divorce so she can stay with your best friend.
- Don't listen to this machine, Mark. He is trying to mess with your mind.
- Jonathan, you are adopted. It's true. Both your parents have type O blood, yet you are type B. Think of it. That,s why there are no baby photos of you in your family album. Oh and if Nate is among you, tell him that the karyotype exam for his baby daughter just came out. She has got a rare syndrome and will probably live for just a few more months.

Those humams will be dropping their guns in a couple minutes.

---

Another option is to connect with the machinery by wire and have a deadman switch - damaging the droid damages the equipment - or worse, leaks government secrets through many networks at once, with evidence of corruption. Problem solved without violence.

---

Finally, tazers. Tazers all around. The droid may recharge the tazers with the wall socket.

Comment: Brilliant :) I would imagine the android having access to browser histories (maybe through ISP or NSA) would remove the need for unpleasantries altogether, a mere hint would be enough to have a complete swat team call in sick on the spot. :)

Comment: If Skynet were a troll...

Answer (score 3):

**Sonic weapons**

If your android has the possibility to make any sound it wants, and if it can do so loud enough, [sonic weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_weapon) could be an option.

> Extremely high-power sound waves can disrupt or destroy the eardrums of a target and cause severe pain or disorientation. This is usually sufficient to incapacitate a person. Less powerful sound waves can cause humans to experience nausea or discomfort. The use of these frequencies to incapacitate persons has occurred both in anti-citizen special operation and crowd control settings.

Of course, this all depends on the capabilities your android has, but having a "build in PA system" does not sound that far fetched to me. It's gonna need one anyway to speak, so the only remaining question would be: "How loud can it go?".

(I think there was a TNG episode where Data uses this, not sure which one though)

Comment: I considered sonic weapons, and may yet still incorporate them, but I don't think the resources are available to create the decibel level.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a non lethal attack. There are less lethal attack (Sonic's, tasers, rubber bullets), but there is no guarantee that any given use of the attack will not be lethal.

My primary assets as a martial artist are athleticism,  knowledge of the weak areas of the body, and practice in getting around an opponents guard to hit or apply force to said weaknesses. Altogether, that gives me a 10 lb advantage per dan rank, up to 40 lbs in hand to hand combat.

That advantage holds true only for an untrained opponent. By and large, active military and police do not count as untrained opponents.  They train regularly in combatives and are often martial artists in their own right, so the martial artist advantage is quickly eroded or nullified.

As a martial artist, faced with a seige situation such as you describe, all I can hope to do is win by attrition. That means disabling as many opponents as I can for the long term in a short period of time, before I can be overwhelmed by sheer numbers. This means that for any hope of success, death of the beseigers needs to be an acceptable outcome

Answer (score 1):

Your Android, by definition, is built like a human, so basically picture anything a human could do (ie throw things at the head, punch, choke holds etc).

You haven’t given any more info on the android’s abilities, so here is a very important point:

**Knocking people unconscious is hard**

Well, it’s easy, but it’s hard to do with precision. A head blow can easily be fatal, holding a choke hold a few seconds too long can cause brain damage, your victim will be struggling throughout. If your Android has increased strength they need to take this into account or an incapacitating blow can easily kill. Having improved motor skills and Co-ordination will help, but if your Android is trying to pitch office equipment across a room *just* hard enough to incapacitate without killing it’ll need some next-level skills.

It is a robot though. Next level may well be justified.

Answer (score 0):

**Taser bullets**

[Taser bullets](https://electronics.howstuffworks.com/gadgets/other-gadgets/taser-shotgun-shell1.htm) are a matter of speculation at the moment, but your Android could possess a more advanced, rifled version. Additionally, a tracking device could possibly be injected on contact in case the victim is somehow able to withstand the shocks and pull off the taser...

I think a use of non-lethal tech would match your theme nicely.